# How to create a blinking element in a UI frame

Tags: dialog, dm-script

I have a nice UIframe dialog and would like to have a button that when pressed causes an element (i.e., small image) in the UI to blink.  Pressing a second button should stop the element from blinking.  Any example code available?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please show what you have written so far. Just asking for example code is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific animated UI element available in DM scripting. However, I was successful with creating a 'blinking' element by using a periodic main thread to regularly alternate a bitmap element. 
Here is the example code:

```
Class myBlinkDotDLG : UIframe
{
    number onBlink
    number periodicTaskID

    image GetDotImage( object self, number highlight )
    {
        image dot := realimage( "Dot", 4,40,40)
        dot = iradius < 20 ? (20-iradius) : 0
        dot /= max(dot)

        RGBImage colDot = highlight ? (RGB(255,180,0)*dot) : (RGB(250,80,0)*dot)
        colDot = RGB( Red(colDot)+75,Green(colDot)+76,Blue(colDot)+78)
        return  ColDot
    }

    void StartBlink( object self )
    {
        if ( 0 == periodicTaskID )
            periodicTaskID = AddMainThreadPeriodicTask( self,"BlinkToggle", 0.5 )
    }

    void StopBlink( object self )
    {
        if ( 0 != periodicTaskID )
            RemoveMainThreadTask( periodicTaskID )

        periodicTaskID = 0
    }

    void BlinkToggle( object self )
    {
        onBlink = !onBlink
        Result( "\n Blink:" + onBlink )
        taggroup dotTG = self.LookUpElement("Dot")
        if ( dotTG.TagGroupisValid()) 
            dotTG.DLGGetElement(0).DLGBitmapData(self.GetDotImage(onBlink))
        else
            self.StopBlink()    // Important! You need to unregister the mainthread task if there is no dialog anymore
    }

    object CreateAndShowDialog( object self )
    {
        TagGroup DLG, DLGitems
        DLG = DLGCreateDialog( "Test", DLGitems )

        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateGraphic(40,40).DLGAddBitmap( self.GetDotImage(1) ).DLGIdentifier("Dot") )
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( "Blinking\tDot" ))
        DLG.DLGTableLayout(2,1,0)
        self.Init( DLG ).Display( "Blinky" )
        self.StartBlink()
        return self
    }
}

Alloc( myBlinkDotDLG ).CreateAndShowDialog()
```

Note that the registered periodic task will keep the UIframe object in scope, even if the dialog window is closed.
However, the `LookupElement()` command will not return a valid TagGroup when the dialog window no longer exists, so I have used this to check for this condition and automatically unregister the task, should it still be running.

My example code doesn't have a button to start/stop the blinking, but that would be straight forward to add. Just have the according action methods call `StartBlink` and `StopBlink`